# Flex container not getting full width of its children

Tags: html, css

Consider the following simple flex grid:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  padding: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

I need my `container:hover` to go though the whole line. Repair that the orange hover line does not get large enough to hover into all children (scroll to right to see the effect).

How to make `container` get width of its `children` ?

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex

Comment: and  remove the width:100% (replace it with min-width)

Comment: @Termani: Your suggestion does not work. Same problem: `.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: it does for me: https://jsfiddle.net/0qhxovfc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the width of **.container** is smaller, then width of all of children combined.

**UPDATE** You should switch parent to **display: inline-flex;** and remove **width: 100%;**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;      
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  padding: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-wrap` will make my line breaks. The flex childs must remain the same. Also, hovering on child will not make my container grow. My question is how to make the container grow.

Comment: Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hover to cover all children, you should apply it to the children:

```
.container:hover .child {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Note: This will repair what you wanted fixed, but will *not* directly make the container get the width of its children.

Best